# Python pip install: error: package directory 'b' does not exist

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I am making a simple proof of concept example for my thesis about python package distribution. I am stuck on example where I want to install a simple package.

Folder and files layout is the following:

```
baseApp/
├── baseApp
│   ├── app.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

File `setup.py` contains:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='BaseApp',
    version='1.0',
    packages="baseApp",
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'baseApp=baseApp.app:main '
        ]
    }
)
```

File `app.py` is simple file with one function:

```py
def main():
    print("main function")
```

My idea was to install this package using `pip`, but running `pip install ./baseApp` always gives error message:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating BaseApp.egg-info
writing BaseApp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to BaseApp.egg-info/depjjjendency_links.txt
writing entry points to BaseApp.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing top-level names to BaseApp.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'BaseApp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
error: package directory 'b' does not exist
```

Even trying to navigate into the folder and then running `python setup.py install` gives me the same error. What bothers me the most is that I don't understand what the error message was trying to say to me. I don't see any directory called `b` nor the reason why there shold be one.

I also tried using virtual environment and system distribution, but both resulted in same error message.

My question is what causes this behaviour and is there any easy way to solve it or am I missing something?

Comment: Try `packages=["baseApp"]`, I'm pretty sure this is supposed to be a list.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you! It solved it.

Comment: Background: When a list is expected, and you give a string, then Python treats that string as a list (of letters). So in your case it would have been treated as `packages=['b', 'a', 's', 'e', 'A', 'p', 'p']`, which explains the error you saw.

Comment: Since we're getting into it, I think it even has some more algorithms behind it since output to file `top_level.txt` is `A a b e p s`, which actually contains all the letters needed to make the word `baseApp` sorted alphabetically. I suspected it since it was strange, but I thought it had nothing to do with it. Now the file contains only `baseApp` in it

Comment: Yes, I suppose it internally de-duplicates the packages list to prevent unnecessary includes. That it ends up sorted is a side-effect of that de-duplication.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have the same problem because package was not installed completely so i installed it again and then everything goes well

Comment: I tried installing and uninstalling multiple times and it didn't work. Solved it by making `packages` entry a list

Answer (score 0):

In `setup.py`, the field `packages` is meant to be a list.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='BaseApp',
    version='1.0',
    packages=["baseApp"],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'baseApp=baseApp.app:main '
        ]
    }
)
```